# Calling method inside timers timer Elapsedevent

Tags: c#, synchronization, thread-safety, system.timers.timer

I want to know is it always required to put lock keyword when we are calling method inside timers elapsed to achieve thread safety of that method.

I have a code that is not using any shared variable and calling inside Elapsedevent.
Do I need to lock it or it will be fine since the threads are having their own stack.

Here is my Elapsedevent code,

```
void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Test t = new Test();
    t.Process();
}    

class Test
{
    public void Process()
    {    
        // do ingsome processing using only local variables.
    }
}
```

Comment: If a method has no observable side-effects at all then it probably should be deleted since it doesn't accomplish anything.  There's something hidden in the Process() method that we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method which doesn't uses shared state, that is inherently thread safe. You don't need a lock at all.